# Is there an idom for building a map with the same keys and values as variables?

Tags: elixir

What I want to do is build an Elixir map with the shortest amount of code with the same variable names as keys and the values of the variables as values of a map. Example:

```
    first_name = "Michael"
    last_name = "Blomponets"
```

The map would look like

```
%{
    "first_name" => "Michael",
    "last_name" => "Blomponets",
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way is explicitly declaring the map exactly how you want it. However, if you absolutely want a shorthand (I wouldn't recommend this), you can accomplish it with a macro:

```rb
defmodule MapShorthand do
  @doc """
  Allows for map shorthand.

    iex> ~~~%{a, b: %{c: d}} = %{a: 3, b: %{c: 4}}
    %{a: 3, b: %{c: 4}}
    iex> {a, d}
    {3, 4}
    iex> ~~~%{a, b: %{c: d}}
    %{a: 3, b: %{c: 4}}

  """
  defmacro ~~~map do
    Macro.postwalk(map, fn
      {:%{}, meta, pairs} ->
        pairs =
          Enum.map(pairs, fn
            value = {key, _meta, context} when is_atom(key) and is_atom(context) ->
              {key, value}

            pair ->
              pair
          end)

        {:%{}, meta, pairs}

      ast ->
        ast
    end)
  end
end
```

It takes in your map, and anywhere it sees a variable instead of a {key, value} pair, it creates a {key, value} pair where the key is the name of the variable. You can name your macro whatever you want, too. I just went with a unary operator.

You can then use JavaScript-style shorthand:

```rb
iex> import MapShorthand, only: [~~~: 1]
MapShorthand
iex> ~~~%{name, age: %{years: age}} = %{name: "Ron", age: %{years: 42, months: 8}}
%{age: %{months: 8, years: 42}, name: "Ron"}
iex> ~~~%{name, age}
%{age: 42, name: "Ron"}
```

Comment: That's pretty cool. I remembered a language feature in coffeescript that allowed an object to be built just by using variable names. I got it to work with my above code using `~~~%{first_name, last_name}` to create the map.

Comment: @yuguang you’d better listen to what experienced developers told you. Andrea Leopardi (the author of `short_maps`, also the [tag:elixir] core team member) abandoned support for his own library. People who _can_ implement that yell “do not do that” in chorus. Count my vote to _never ever_ use this. Define a map, don’t try to save several keystrokes. This looks fancy, but only for newbies. Professionals tend to make the code easy to read and to reason about.

Comment: I am not using it, because I know it may have issues with upgrades even if I wrote a bunch of tests to cover it. I just wanted to find out if Elixir had a syntax for constructing maps using variables

Answer (score 1):

Advice from someone who wrote a library to do this, then decided it was a bad idea:

https://andrealeopardi.com/posts/a-story-of-regret-and-retiring-a-library-from-hex/

> short_maps adds magic to Elixir. When someone uses short_maps in their codebase, it forces folks that read that codebase – even experienced Elixir developers – to know about it. Being a syntax feature, it’s really in your face and it makes code hard to read if you are not familiar with it. The distinction between atom keys and string keys is also not obvious, with the result being code that looks more obfuscated.

Comment: Andrea loathes that library and he's also a member of the core team. I can say from having used that library it's pretty much hell after a while and is more painful than not to use. Great link.

Answer (score 0):

To echo what others have said, in general it's not worth it to introduce a custom macro at the cost of having custom language extensions that are unique to your code base (aka the Haskell problem).

**However**, in the specific case where you need to export **all** variables into a map or keyword list, you can use `binding/1`.

```
iex(1)> a = 1
1
iex(2)> b = 2
2
iex(3)> binding()
[a: 1, b: 2]
iex(4)> Map.new(binding())
%{a: 1, b: 2}
```

In my opinion there are only two places that this has a place, within macros, and within test setup blocks.

It can help reduce boilerplate in the case of tests:

```
  setup do
    author = insert(:author)
    post = insert(:post, author: author)
    comment = insert(:comment, post: post)
    [author: author, post: post, comment: comment]
  end
```

Becomes:

```
  setup do
    author = insert(:author)
    post = insert(:post, author: author)
    comment = insert(:comment, post: post)
    binding()
  end
```

Like all things, use your judgement :).